# Why do I lose my instance variables when I invoke Shoes#'visit'?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I'm sure this has to do with the intricacies mentionned in Shoes > Manual > Rules but I just don't get it. If someone would care to explain why @var == nil in the following code ... 
I thought I could use visit to switch between different views in my application but that won't work if I lose all state.

```
class MyShoe < Shoes
  url '/', :index
  url '/somewhere', :somewhere

  def index
    @var = para link( "go somewhere", :click => "/somewhere" )
  end

  def somewhere
    para "var = #{@var.inspect}"  
  end
end

Shoes.app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_`why himself has answered this issue, and I'll get to that in a minute.  First, the simplest way to pass data (specifically, strings) between different urls is like this:

```
class MyShoe < Shoes
  url '/', :index
  url '/somewhere/(\d+)', :somewhere

  def index
    @var = para link( "What is 2 + 2?", :click => "/somewhere/4" )
  end

  def somewhere(value)
    para "2 + 2 = #{value}"  
  end
end

Shoes.app
```

It will match the subgroups of the regex and pass the matching strings as parameters to the method.  Occasionally useful, but it gets unwieldy in a hurry.  The other solution is to use constants or class variables, as [`_`why explains here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.shoes/3205):

> > OK, so fooling around further it looks like all instance variables get
> >
> > wiped at the beginning of every method within a Shoes subclass.
> >     That's OK I guess.  So what's the preferred way to have some data
> >     that's shared from one Shoes URL to another?  Passing it from one page
> >     to the next in the URL itself works -- if it's a string.  If it's not
> >     a string, what should you use -- @@class_variables?
>
> Sure you could use a class var. Those
>   are guaranteed to persist throughout
>   the life of the app. Or a constant.
>
> Also, Shoes comes with SQLite3, data
>   can be passed there.

In your example, it would look like this:

```
class MyShoe < Shoes
  url '/', :index
  url '/somewhere', :somewhere

  def index
    @@var = para link( "go somewhere", :click => "/somewhere" )
  end

  def somewhere
    para "var = #{@@var.inspect}"  
  end
end

Shoes.app
```

Comment: Thanks again Pesto. I think I'm done pestering you for the day :-)